What writing system are they using in "Wise Man's Grandchild"?
What language or writing system are the characters using in the anime, "Wise Man's Grandchild"?
For Example:

Is it just a made up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?

There's not enough words to confirm, but it looks like the text says:
MPARTHAZ | WARUIO:

EDIT:
Could also be: "PART I AII | WARUI 0"
More words are needed to draw conclusions.

I see. Maybe I should rewatch the anime to find more scenes with this writing system.
